Deepspeed JSON config file being ignored
this is my first time writing on this platform, I apologise if there is any issue with the way the question is being asked.
I am trying to run a python file with certain deepspeed configurations such as activation checkpointing, the configurations have been placed into a config.json file as such:
{
"train_micro_batch_size_per_gpu":128,
"optimizer": {
"type": "Adam",
"params": {
"lr": 3e-4
}
},
"gradient_clipping": 1.0,
"activation_checkpointing": {
"partition_activations":true,
"cpu_checkpointing":false,
"contiguous_memory_optimization":true,
"number_checkpoints": 12,
"synchronize_checkpoint_boundary":true,
"profile":true
},
"fp16": {
"enabled": true
}
}


To run my code I execute this line:
deepspeed --num_nodes=2 --hostfile ./hostfile --num_gpus=2 ./rundeepspeed.py \
\--deepspeed \
\--deepspeed_config ./ds_config.json

However upon running this line of code, it seems to ignore the json file and state all parameters as false.
For further information, the first chunk of my rundeepspeed.py file is as such
import deepspeed

def add_argument():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='CIFAR')  
parser.add_argument('--local_rank', type=int, default=-1,
help='local rank passed from distributed launcher')
parser = deepspeed.add_config_arguments(parser)
args = parser.parse_args()
return args

args = add_argument()

deepspeed.init_distributed()

I have checked whether the json config parameters have impacted the run by including deepspeed.checkpointing.is_configured() in the python file, and it always returns as false.
I have also tried to use define the configurations using a python dict but the changes will be overwritten.
I have also tried to configure activation checkpointing using deepspeed.checkpointing.configure(mpu_, deepspeed_config=None, partition_activations=None, contiguous_checkpointing=None, num_checkpoints=None, checkpoint_in_cpu=None, synchronize=None, profile=None) but it throws an error that mpu_ is not defined.
I am expecting the output to reflect the configurations defined in my JSON file.

Please check your Python code, it needs to be indented correctly. You could do the same with your JSON, too, in order to make it easier to read. As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask] to avoid common pitfalls, but apart from the formatting your question looks sound to me.
